# How to create Python Selenium Chrome webdriver remote with Current user data?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, grid, webdriver

1. How I create LOCAL Chrome Webdriver WITH Current user data

   ```
   chromedriver = "/Users....../chromedriver"
   os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=/Users..../Google/Chrome")
   webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver,
                         chrome_options=options)
   ```
2. How I create REMOTE Chrome webdriver with clear - new user data

   ```
   webdriver.Remote(command_executor="http://192.168.1.30:4441/wd/hub",
               desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
   ```

Now, How create Remote Chrome webdriver with current user data?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/Users..../Google/Chrome")
webdriver.Remote("http://192.168.1.30:4441/wd/hub",
        options.to_capabilities())
```

And if you have your chromedriver.exe on the PATH then you should not need this part:

`chromedriver = "/Users....../chromedriver"`

Not sure if that works for you, but here is an example that let me start remote chrome webdriver with desired chromeOption for language:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--lang=de")
chrome_remote = webdriver.Remote('http://hostname:4444/wd/hub', options.to_capabilities())
```